# Table-cell breaks on window resize in Safari

Tags: css, safari, responsive-design, media-queries, css-tables

I have a table built out of `div` elements. By default elements display as table-cell.
On `@media screen and (max-width: 769px)` elements need to become `table-row`.

Every browser works fine except Safari.
In safari it shows fine until I re-size window to very narrow and then back full width. at that point table breaks. if I refresh page or disable and re-enable `table-cell` style table fixes itself.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sergejpopov/TvEWf/

Is that a Safari bug? How to fix?

Comment: I've had a similar issue in Chrome. I think it is a webkit rendering bug. Never found a fix for it

Comment: I have an similar problem on an ajax page. Changing the content of the div having display:table-cell does not resize the table-cell. So I have to reset it using jQuery `$('.col').css('display', table-cell);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're not adhering to a correct structure- you shouldn't swap out `table-cell` for `table-row`, they serve two distinctly different purposes which are not equivalent in terms of interpreted layout, the table structure should always follow:

```
table (display-table)
 row (display-row) <- important to denote a row of elements
  cell (display-cell) <- important to denote (column based) content within a row
  /cell
 /row
/table
```

You're missing out either the row or cell level with your approach, so although everythign seems to be interpreted correctly for the most part, your css is actually in error.

I would suggest you consider using floated or inline divs, see

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TvEWf/1/)**

HTML

```
<div class="t">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.t
{
    width:100%;
}

.t>div
{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    width:25%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    zoom:1;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
.t
{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

.t>div
{
    border:1px solid red;        
    display: block;
        width:100%;
    zoom:1;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out table structure problem. I ended up using no tables on narrow screen, but I still left table on large screen as need elements to span across full width of the screen. (amount of columns is not constant - so using floated/inline divs is not an option)